# break strings of link in an array xcode

Tags: objective-c

Do you know how to break a string in using objective c and fed it into an array ? i am new to c environment and am finding it hard to get this. please help

e.g. x://xxx; x://soe;x://roy

result:

1. x://wwww
2. x://soe
3. x://roy

note: break point ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
NSString *str = x://xxx; x://soe;x://roy;
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Comment: You do not need the alloc/init, its result is thrown away without being used on the next line.

Comment: s u r right, there is no need of this, I had edited my answer.

Comment: `NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Refer following code this  will help you:

```
NSString *string = @"x://xxx; x://soe;x://roy";
NSArray *listItems = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Please do some googling before posting the question.